How to skip iteraction and referring the new one to two previous ones
I have a dictionaries with key having values for each time intervals.
For each new time t, functions perform calculation by using dictionary values at t-1.
Now, I have a problem with t 1681, which I want to skip.
Original:
for t in time: 

    ELZfarm_m_h2_production=0
    ELZfarm_m_O2_production=0
    h2_net_to_change_from_storage=0

    # System consumption at t-1
    # Power consumed by the ELZs
    P_ELZ_inoperation_tbefore = sum(ELZmodule[key]['Power'][t-1] for key in ELZmodule.keys() ) # MW
    # Power consumed by UTILITIES
    Power_consump_utilities_Mw= sum(Power_consumption_utilities[key][t-1] for key in Power_consumption_utilities.keys() )  # MW
    # Total Power consumed by the system
    Power_consump_system_tot_Mw = P_ELZ_inoperation_tbefore + Power_consump_utilities_Mw # MW

    # Determing the total Delta Power variation from t-1
    Delta_P_system = Psolar[t] - Power_consump_system_tot_Mw # MW
 
    # Positive Delta Power Variation
    if Delta_P_system >= 0:
    ......

Idea:
for t in time: 

    if t == 1861:
        continue

    elif t == 1862:
        t-1 = 1860

    ELZfarm_m_h2_production=0
    ELZfarm_m_O2_production=0
    h2_net_to_change_from_storage=0

    # System consumption at t-1
    # Power consumed by the ELZs
    P_ELZ_inoperation_tbefore = sum(ELZmodule[key]['Power'][t-1] for key in ELZmodule.keys() ) # MW
    # Power consumed by UTILITIES
    Power_consump_utilities_Mw= sum(Power_consumption_utilities[key][t-1] for key in Power_consumption_utilities.keys() )  # MW
    # Total Power consumed by the system
    Power_consump_system_tot_Mw = P_ELZ_inoperation_tbefore + Power_consump_utilities_Mw # MW

    # Determing the total Delta Power variation from t-1
    Delta_P_system = Psolar[t] - Power_consump_system_tot_Mw # MW
 
    # Positive Delta Power Variation
    if Delta_P_system >= 0:
    ......

I'm aware it cannot be written like that.
Do you have any help for that?
Thanks for the collaboration.

Hello user, **for i in range( len( time )): if time[ i ] == 1861:
continue
elif time[ i ] == 1862:
    i -= 1 #?**.


I don't think you can assign to t-1. Something like:
if t == 1861:
    continue

if t == 1862:
    previous = 1860
else:
    previous = t - 1

a = arr[previous]

you could also do somethine like:
a = arr[1860 if t == 1862 else t - 1]

